# I am calling a function onclick, and setting a timeout for 1 second, how can I disable the timeout from that function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button which will activate a function on click, the function has a set timeout on it, so it repeats

```
function chooseNum() {
    let timeout = setTimeout(chooseNum, 1000);
}
```

I want to disable it in another function, I tried this:

```
function initStop() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

the HTML is like this:

```
<button onclick="initStop()" id="stop" class="btn btnStop">Stop</button>
<button onclick="chooseNum()" id="start" class="btn btn1">Start</button>
```

Comment: `timeout` only exists with in `chooseNum`. You need to make the variable global if you want other methods to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the **timeout** is local to the **chooseNum** function

To solve your problem do

```
var timeout;

function chooseNum() {
    timeout = setTimeout(chooseNum, 1000);
}

function initStop() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

This creates the timout variable in global scope, and initialized in the **chooseNum()** function.